# Repeat Function Until Finished?

Tags: javascript, node.js, loops, concurrency

I have a function with an argument I want to have run repeatedly, in-order, until a status code check is correct.

```
    function check( id ){
    var status = 2; 
    var exit = 0;
    // set status based on web request with ID param
    switch( status ){
        // based on status code, output a message and set exit 0/1
    }

    /** Here I want the Function to repeat itself with a delay without skipping until exit is 1 **/
    
}
```

I Tried using the async.whilst library, but I couldn't figure out how to keep the id parameter and use the callback.

I also tried the setTimeout method, but it flooded the console and crashed.

Thanks in advance for any help that you can give me.

## Edit

Here's the Full Code, it's pretty ghetto, but i'm new to this event-based stuff

```
function checkStatusLoop( tradeID ){ //checks if the trade is on-going or not ( 0 - done, 1 - ongoing )
    var status = -1; // set default to active
    var exit = 0;
    manager.getOffer( tradeID, function( err, offer ) {
        if( err ) throw err;
        status = offer.state;
    });
    switch( status ){
        case 1:
            console.log('Trade #' + tradeID + ' Invalid');
            exit = 1;
            break;
        case 2:
            console.log('Trade #' + tradeID + ' Active');
            exit = 0;
            break;
        case 3:
            console.log('Trade #' + tradeID + ' Accepted!');
            exit = 1;
            break;
        case 4:
            console.log('Trade #' + tradeID + ' Countered');
            exit = 1;
            break;
        case 5:
            console.log('Trade #' + tradeID + ' Expired');
            exit = 1;
            break;
        case 6:
            console.log('Trade #' + tradeID + ' Canceled');
            exit = 1;
            break;
        case 7:
            console.log('Trade #' + tradeID + ' Declined');
            exit = 1;
            break;
        case 8:
            console.log('Trade #' + tradeID + ' InvalidItems');
            exit = 1;
            break;
        case 9:
            console.log('Trade #' + tradeID + ' EmailPending');
            exit = 0;
            break;
        case 10:
            console.log('Trade #' + tradeID + ' EmailCanceled');
            exit = 0;
            break;
        default:
            console.log('Trade #' + tradeID + ' Bad State!');
            exit = 1;
            break;
    }
    if( exit == 0 ){
        setTimeout(function(){
            checkStatusLoop( tradeID );
        }, 2000);
    } else {
        return ( TradeOfferManager.getStateName(status) );
    }
}
```

This Library is from github: https://github.com/DoctorMcKay/node-steam-tradeoffer-manager/wiki/TradeOfferManager#getofferid-callback

Whoops, apparently there's an on('sentOfferChanged', shame that I spent a good while on this

Comment: Do not forget that your "web request" is probably asynchronous, meaning that it won't return a value and the control will return immediately. Therefore, your status will always end up being undefined.

Comment: yeah, what do I do for that? I just noticed that too, first time doing node.js. While loops don't work

Comment: It depends what API you use to perform the request. Is it a promise-based API (returns a promise)? If it is you might want to write your code like: function `check(id) {  makeRequest(id).then(function (status) { /*rest of your code goes here/* }); }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 function check( id ){
    var status = 2; //default of 2
    var exit = 0;

    // set status based on web request with ID param
    switch( status ){
        // based on status code, output a message and set exit 0/1
    }

    /** Here I want the Function to repeat itself with a delay without skipping until exit is 1 **/
    //but I need the browser to update, so I cannot run check immedeately.
    setTimeout(function() {
       check( id );
    }, 100)
}
```

?

Comment: Wow uh, I'm not sure why it wasn't working earlier, I didn't use an anonymous function in the setTimeout function and it was crashing, I feel really dumb now.

Comment: I'm trying to do something like a while loop that goes until the variable is set from the web request, but it's garbage too

Comment: missed the ajax request in the middle of the call sorry. - what you want to do is not the correct way of doing this. You should design for eventhandling on the ajax callback function